# Is there a benefit of using the "user_" prefix in Extension Keys?

Tags: namespaces, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I have seen quite some "project specific extensions" from various developers and never saw the"user_" prefix, even though
the [documenatation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtensionKey/Index.html) instructs to use it:

> Project specific extensions (not generally usable or shareable):
>   Select any name you like and prepend it “user_” (which is the only
>   allowed use of a key starting with “u”). This prefix denotes that this
>   extension is a local one which does not come from the central TYPO3
>   Extension Repository or is ever intended to be shared. Probably this
>   is an “adhoc” extension you have made for some special occasion.

But developers tend to use "client_usecase" or just "usecase", if my perception is representative. I was told that "user_" enlarges several things like database-table-names unnecessarily and the extensions's namespace (vendor-name/extension-name) is more important than the extension-key and this part of the documentation may more or less be a remnant of the past.

My concern was, that such an extension key could conflict with other extensions, f. e. the Extension Manager may try to download translations and suggest to download updates, problems with dependencies may occur, or TYPO3 Hosters may install security patches, etc. I'm personally using this prefix in my user_site extensions (project specific TS and Templates) for several projects and was expecting some conditions in the core, f. e. that the Extension Manager skips any translation updates for this extension, but I couldn't find anything. Maybe I should suggest (forge) to exclude such extensions for version and translation updates and highlight it as "project specific" in the Extension-Manager-list.

I thought that there are only two options: register an extension key or use the "user_"-prefix, but this seems to be outdated, or at least commonly ignored.

Is there still a benefit of using such prefix and is this the way to go, or will the extension key registration possibly be replaced by something like a vendor-name TER registration in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation always was an recommendation - and (nearly?) no one used extension with a key beginning with `user_`.

It was an recommendation to avoid conflicts like you described. But the conflicts were avoided with prefixes of programmer, company or client (which is like a vendor name).
In the old days not only tables were prefixed with the extensionkey, but also additional fields to other tables. especially if you used the `kickstarter`/`extensionbuilder`.

Today we use namespaces to avoid conflicts with class names, but still can get conflicts with extension keys as any vendor names does not count if the extension is installed beyond `typo3conf/ext/`.
The folder probably could be renamed, but having the same kind of records (with different fields) in tables with identical names could break the system.

Example: don't try to introduce an own extension for news named `news` ;-)

On the other hand you might get fields with identical information but different names:
`latitude/longitude`, `lat/long`, `lat/lon`.
And what about fields which are named identical from different extensions which use different data representations? `time` as `string`, `unixtimestamp`, `time`, ...

Conclusion: you can't avoid all conflicts, and being aware of possible problems might help to avoid it with some smart assumptions.

The auto-update for extensions can only occur with a composer-install, but there the vendor name is important. 
In an installation without composer you might get an extension from TER where the extension key is identical to an own extension, but it should be known if the own (local) extension has newer versions in TER. especially if the extension has a prefix from author, company or client.

Be aware that extensions are available not only in TER. With composer and packagist extensions can be stored anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The risk of conflicts seems to be marginal, if choosing a prefix, which is as unique as possible. Nevertheless I still don't get why everyone prefers this, instead of "user_", which only seems to have advantages and no downside (right?): With 4 letters it is quiet short. You don't have to think up a good prefix. Other developers will recognize this as "local" immediately. It's impossible that someone registers the same key and uploads something to TER, from where you might get wrong translations when updating translations in BE.

Comment: your thoughts are correct, but I suppose (IMHO) that the usage of `user-` prefix was not used widely as it was nasty to rename an extension in case it got popular or that the developer tried to make a name while putting their initials into the extension key. some developer got a good name and extensions with their initials were a quality sign. And what bonus do you get if you see an extension `user_news` in an installation? if you supervise multiple sites and in each installation is an extension `user_news`: are they individual to the customer or the agency or the author or all the same?

Comment: I would assume that they are individual to the installation, as the docu says "project specific". I guess it would be nice, if one could register a TER-Prefix once, especially for those who don't wan't to publish an extension and usually skips registering keys for small project specific extensions ...

Comment: If I'm familiar with something I like to reuse it. ;-) if those extensions all are individual: how do I do the managing? with the same name I would expect the same or at least similar behaviour. So the code probably has something in common. but maintenance for multiple branches/versions will be hell. Imagine a bugfix you have to apply to 5 or more branches/versions.

Comment: Some (mostly small) extensions in my projects are so unique that they won't be reused. It's a different case if you intend to reuse it. I would prefix those with my developer-prefix and register the key in TER and maybe use different branches for projects/clients.